# PHP get variables from JavaScript onClick (HTML)?

Tags: php, javascript, html, variables, get

I need to get variables from a html link, this is the link and when it is clicked it shows the popup window.

```
<a href='#' onclick=\"show('poruka');var idporuke=$porid; \">Pogledaj<a>
```

And I have `var idporuke=$porid;` which is working like a charm. But I need to pass that variable to php script? I can't use GET or POST methods.

Comment: If you can't use the "GET" or "POST" methods to send you data you are SOL.

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to have to, or some form of AJAX

Comment: How can i do it ? ... I can use "GET" and "POST" but how do i do it with link ? .. Btw. When i use post and get the popup window dissapear :S

Comment: @haris: Can you use jQuery ??

Comment: You have to use Javascript's XMLHTTPRequest object to create a request (GET or POST) and send it. It will load without refreshing the current page. Or, you could use an `iframe` HTML element.

Comment: @NAVEED: Is jQuery the new regex? :P

Comment: @Ryan Sullivan that is not true.. there is another "elegent" way :)

Comment: @NAVEED Yes , but i don't now jQuery very well :)

Comment: @Ryan Sullivan : Can you show me or give me a tutorial of that PLS :)

Comment: @haris: Look at this http://jquery.com/

Comment: Here is a _great_ free jQuery tutorial: [http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp)

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<img src="about:blank" id="fake_request" style="position:absolute; top: -20px;left:-20px;width:1px;height:1px;" />

<a href='#' onclick=\"show('poruka');var idporuke=$porid; document.getElementById('fake_request').src='/myPhpScript.php?idporuke='+idporuke+';">Pogledaj<a>
```

something like this

Comment: I would not consider this very elegant, an `iframe` would do just as well, plus it is more correct for a request

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href='#' onclick="show('poruka');var idporuke=$porid;">Pogledaj<a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to pass a browser side variable to a server side script. PHP does all of its processing, then the HTML/Javascript takes over. The only methods you have for passing a variable through from browser to server are via either a page refresh or Javascript AJAX. If you absolutely cannot use POST or GET, you could use Cookies (http://techpatterns.com/downloads/javascript_cookies.php) or Sessions...although I am pretty sure sessions are not supported in Javascript. I would recommend using POST or GET depending on the variable size - Cookies come with a lot of limitations and conditions.